# Why does Android 7 reset default Home app after boot?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, default-applications, troubleshooting, home-screen

Edit: I've got an app that was set as the HOME app that suddenly isn't set as the HOME app. My question is in two parts:

1. Does Android 7 have the capacity to do that on its own?
2. If it does, what sorts of misbehaviour might cause that to happen?

---

I've installed an app and set it as the default HOME app by selecting it and "ALWAYS" from the popup window you get when you press the HOME button.  It works most of the time - if I press the HOME button then the app runs, or if I switch the phone off/on then the app runs.

However, sometime when I switch the phone on, I get the "Use XXXX as Home / JUST ONCE / ALWAYS / Use a different app / Launcher3" popup.  Why would Android stop running a 3rd party app as the default HOME app?

I only get this problem on Android 7 devices - I haven't seen it with 4.4 to 6.0 - has something changed in 7 that makes it more picky about this sort of thing?

The app is on a private channel so, sorry, I can't give you a link to it. And the devices are from Tokie and K-Mobile so not off-the-shelf consumer products.

Comment: I've noted that the app is on a private channel, and given the make of the devices.

Comment: Could you clarify which launcher? If the app/launcher crashes Android restarts it. Could be possible that the app is reverting to the default launcher as a fallback mechanism because something is wrong

Comment: @verdant the app isn't on the play store so I can't give you access to it, sorry. The logs don't show any signs of a crash. Fundamentally I'm trying to find out whether Android will ever remove the "Default HOME" attribute from an app. If it won't then there's no point in asking about circumstances - something else must be going on.